# Signal Deconvolution Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, deconvolution

I'm having some issues with signal deconvolution using scipy.signal library. What I'm trying to do is as follows:

I have an array (4096 points) of a signal measured with samples and a signal measured without sample (measurement system response with the same length). In order to obtain a pure sample signal i need to deconvolve those. Here is my code:

```
folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__'))
y_measurement = np.zeros(4096)
y_systemres = np.zeros(4096)
x = ((1.0*np.arange(0,4096,1))*5e3/4096)

file = file_name + ('0%i'%i)[-2:] + '.dat'
file2 = file_name2 + ('0%i'%i)[-2:] + '.dat'
data = np.genfromtxt(os.path.join(folder,file),skip_header = 10).T
data2 = np.genfromtxt(os.path.join(folder,file2),skip_header = 10).T
y_measurement = y_measurement + data
y_systemres = y_systemres + data2
    
rec, rem = deconvolve(y_measurement,y_systemres)

deconv, _ = deconvolve( y_measurement, y_systemres)
n = len(y_measurement)-len(y_systemres)+1
s = (len(y_measuremenet)-n)/2
deconv_res = np.zeros(len(y_measuremenet))
deconv_res[s:len(y_measuremenet)-s-1] = deconv
deconv = deconv_res

mpl.plot(deconv)
```

While running this code I got an error **"BUG: filter coefficient a[0] == 0 not supported yet"**. Can anyone please help me with this? I got a bit lost already. All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a solution. If anyone will be looking for it, here it is:

deconvolve does not like "0" especially in system response. It was enough to get rid of those and everything works. Also those lines:

```
n = len(y_measureme- nt)-len(y_systemres)+1
s = (len(y_measuremenet)-n)/2
deconv_res = np.zeros(len(y_measuremenet))
deconv_res[s:len(y_measuremenet)-s-1] = deconv
deconv = deconv_res
```

were useless.